# The shout symbol?

Tags: comparative-linguistics, sanskrit

[wikipedia : Devnagari :-](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari)  : "The avagraha **ऽ** (usually transliterated with an apostrophe) ***is a Sanskrit punctuation mark*** for the elision of a vowel in sandhi: एकोऽयम् ekoyam (< ekas + ayam) "this one". An original long vowel lost to coalescence is sometimes marked with a double avagraha: सदाऽऽत्मा sadātmā (< sadā + ātmā) "always, the self". **Its main function is to show that a vowel is sustained in a cry or a shout**:"

> **Do we have a similar feature in any other languages? How is the 'stretching' of a long vowel denoted in  other languages** ?

Comment: What's the definition of "sustained" in that quote: original vowel not dropped?

Comment: No, as per rules of Sanskrit a vowel can not be omitted.

Comment: @ARi: As I understand your question avagraha has two functions: (1) Marking vowel elision in sandhi, and (2) expressing a cry or shout. Also, you say function number two is the main function. Is that correct?

Comment: A very good question. Although a shout can be taken as a vowel sound being prolonged which can be done by sandhi.I would like to  know about both.

Comment: I (and I suspect others as well) don't understand what you mean by a 'shout' here.

Comment: I think this question refers to what is called "pluta", a vowel pronounced for a longer duration (of "length" 3 or more, rather than the length 1 of short vowels and length 2 of long vowels). I disagree that this is the main function, though.

Comment: I can't find a reference to double avagraha in either Macdonnell's or Whitney's Sanskrit grammars; from the Wiki article (and the separate article on "avagraha") it looks like it may only be used this way in modern Indic languages. In any case, it seems to be just about elongation, not necessarily shouting. The equivalent in a Roman script would simply be repeating the vowel ("Aaaaaa!").

Comment: @TKR but one can not write a vowel in sanskrit without applying it on a consonent, hence stacking multiple 'a's wont be possible here.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Could you amplify or give examples of 'PLUTA"

Comment: @ShreevatsaR or see my post below.

Comment: Yes, all that is fine. What I disagree with is that pluta is the main function of the avagraha symbol. The Wikipedia page you quoted from specifically says "In Hindi" -- you have removed it while quoting. Also, as @TKR said, it's about elongation (which can happen in a cry or shout, but elsewhere too), not shouting in particular.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Absolutely, I also say that it is used to preserve a vowel sound in sandhi as more than twice the length of a short syllable can not be expressed other wise..Shouting will be just incidental and pertain to the "Vismayadibodhak" ( exclamations) category of words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: extract from google books]

[image: Music and musical thought in early India]

The aspect of pluta is brought out here
........
........

Answer (score 2):

[Suau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suau_language) (Austronesian, PNG) has a particle indicating a continuing action, which is phonetically a long /e/ which can last for as long as a couple of seconds, and is written simply as *eee--*.

```
Abo   i   dalahai,  i   dalahai,  i   lau,  ie  sae,
then  he  take.off  he  take.off  he  go    he  go.up
  ie  sae,   ie  sae,   ie  sae,   ie  sae    eee--,  i   hekau.
  he  go.up  he  go.up  he  go.up  he  go.up  CONT    he  dim
"He was taking off, and going on, going up and up (x5) until he was out of sight."
```

[Source: Russ Cooper (academia.edu)](http://www.academia.edu/3668716/Can_a_top-down_CARLA_Emulate_HARLA_Some_discourse-level_considerations_for_our_next_generation_of_parsers._Proceedings_of_the_1996_General_CARLA_Conference_EditRe-order_section_JAARS_Center_Waxhaw_N.C._November_14_1996)

Comment: The particle indicates continuing action but does not indicate a continuing sound such as "Aaaaaah" which can be written in sanskrit as AssssH, note a vowel can only be applied to a consonent in sanskrit.