# Which languages have words containing the same letter three times in a row?

Tags: orthography, vowels, list-of-languages

I was just reading a french text with the word créées (created). Are there any other languages where triple letters, especially vowels, can be found occasionally?

Comment: Romanian: the plural of _copilul_ ("the child") is _copiii_. The third 'i' is the definite article.

Comment: English actually has a few such words: "goddessship" and "headmistressship" are two.

Comment: Sanskrit has a requirement for having more than two occurrences of a vowel due to rules of sandhi. See this Question http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/4574/2516

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a trivia question. While other list-of-languages questions can serve as the beginnings of a linguistic typology, this kind of orthography question doesn't have any real linguistic merit. All we're doing is identifying quirks at the limits of orthography.

Comment: @curiousdannii This is a good question for http://puzzles.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question has merit to this linguist, who's debugging machine-built pronunciation dictionaries for low-resource languages:  thousands of instances of 'should "aaadaa" and "aadaa" and "aadaaa" be considered the same word in Oromo?'

Comment: Plenty of examples.  But in French, shouldn't 'e' and 'é' be considered different letters? (because the ´ makes it a different vowel, rathe than the same vowel stressed)?

Comment: It would seem more natural to me for the comparative and superlative of "free" to contain "eee" but the English language is evidently averse to such constructions.

Answer (score 20):

It certainly comes up occasionally, but mainly, I would think, across morpheme boundaries where one is a doubled letter and the other is that same letter but in its singular form (as in the new German orthography *Schifffahrt*, *Balletttänzer*, etc) or where a letter has both consonant and vowel values.  Undoubtedly at some point *uvula* and any other words with *uvu* would in the past have been written identically until the separation of the *v* from *u* (if someone could find an old print reference to a *vuvuzela* then you'd have a quadruple *u*).

But I would imagine most languages (happy to be corrected, of course) would start to simplify spelling if the extra letters don't change pronunciation, or add in punctuation to separate them (as in *shell-less* in English)

Comment: Oops, reread the question about vowels, so... my answer is not as useful =/

Comment: No no it's okay! I mistyped. I was looking for repeated letters tripled, not just triple vowels like oiseau. My bad.

Comment: So sad we have little chance to find a Roman inscription about VVVVZELA ...

Comment: @FrédéricGrosshans You'll have to do with VVVLA instead.

Answer (score 18):

Estonian "**jäääär**" ("edge of the ice") comes to mind. It contains the letter **ä** 4 times in a row.

Comment: Is it acceptable to use jaaaar or should one instead write jaa-aar or jaa aar? (accents of course)

Comment: Typologically, Estonian represents a transitional form from an agglutinating language to a fusional language. Nouns with affixes are therefore not all in the dictionary, as they can take many different forms, just like verb conjugations in French. The word **jäääär** comes from _jää_ +‎ _äär_ and is written all in one word.

Comment: @octosquidopus No it isn't. It's *always* written jää äär or jää-äär (depending on the context)

Comment: @jaam is right. It is written jää äär or jää-äär in Estonian texts, but jäääär often comes up in non-Estonian texts discussing the quadrupled "ä" (presumably to emphasize the repetition).

Comment: Similarly, before the spelling reform of 1948, the Danish word for eel caught in the Swedish river of _Råå_ would be written _raaaaaal_ or _Raaaa-aal_. Nowadays, of course, they’re _Råå-ål_ or _rååål_, though I don’t think you’re allowed to fish for them anymore.

Answer (score 16):

In German, you can make up such words on your own, as needed. Find words that ends with two of some vowel, like *schnee* (snow), *tee* (tea) and words that begin with the same letter, and you have:

[Schneeeule](http://www.tierenzyklopaedie.de/tiere/schneeeule.html), also written as Schnee-Eule to make it less confusing.

[image: Schneeeule]

[Teeei](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee-Ei), also written as Tee-Ei to make it less confusing.

[image: Teeei]

Answer (score 14):

Russian has several words with triple letters:

> длинношеее - 'having a long neck', also короткошеее - 'having a short neck'
>
> змееед - 'snake-eater', the name of a bird
>
> доооновский - 'pre-UN'
>
> зоообъединение - 'zoos' association'

Comment: It should be noted thogh that the examples with e have consonant sounds between the vowels (because the last two e-s in the triplex pronounced [jeje]),

Comment: @Anixx - Yes, you're right, but the OP says nothing about sounds, the question is about letters.

Answer (score 13):

In biblical Hebrew, we have חננני "have mercy upon me" (Psalms 9:13 - although that's an unusual form; usually it would be with two נs, and the first would be marked with a gemination symbol) and מממלכה "from one kingdom" (Psalms 105:13 and I Chron. 16:20). Other examples would be possible according to Hebrew grammar, such as וווים "and hooks" or כשששה "when six."

Comment: One could dispute whether this is really three נ in a row, given that there are vowels sounds in there too; it's _hineni_ (or _hinneni_), not _hinnni_.

Answer (score 13):

Ancient Greek has ἀάατος "inviolable".

Answer (score 11):

The number 22 in Dutch ([and other numbers ending with 2](http://www.heardutchhere.net/vocabularynumbers.html)) are written as *tweeëntwintig* - a compound of *twee* (two), *en* (and), and *twintig* (twenty).

In Dutch, the diaeresis are added to the last recurring vowel to indicate a change in syllable; English has this also with *Zoë* and *naïve*.

Comment: My Dutch is rusty by now, but also consider for example `we zijn met 'n tweeën` -- no compounding necessary.

Comment: The same for *zeeën* and *reeën*.

Comment: Before the 1996 spelling reform, there was _zeeëend_, which is now officially spelled _zee-eend_.

Answer (score 10):

Welsh: Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch
(Longest place name)

Swedish: Hawaiiindianer

Norwegian: An ortographic rule makes it impossible with three consonants, and seperates them like this: Trafikk-kork

Comment: I specifically asked my Norwegian teacher about the Norwegian example and he told me that, while examples such as "trafikk-kort" and "trafikk-kork" are possible, he has more frequently seen either "trafikkort" (with a dropped letter) or just plain compounded "trafikkkort". He also said that "trafikk-kort" vs. "trafikkkort" looks to him as more of a register distinction than an orthographical rule following vs. violation

Comment: I was also thinking of LlanfairPG. It depends whether the question is asking about graphemes, so here we have 4 consecutive letters, or whether it was asking about letter in the language's alphabet - in this case, LlanfairPG only has two consecutive letters as <ll> is considered different to <l> in the Welsh alphabet: "<a b c ch d dd e f ff g ng h i j l ll ... y>

Comment: @darkgamma You are absolutely right, I was just giving a quick reference, stating that an ortographic rule stops Norwegian from writing three consecutive identical consonants. I would definetely write trafikkork

Comment: @Danger Fourpence The question is tagged with ortography, so then I thought the asker was looking for letters...

Comment: @Flying Yes. I was just wondering whether <ll> is considered two letters or one. Is it two because it is made up of two graphemes (<l> twice) or is it one letter because it occupied one "slot" in the Welsh alphabet and <l> another.

Comment: <ll> is unambiguously one letter in Welsh, just as <ij> is one letter in Dutch. The fact that they resemble sequences of letters in other languages' writing systems is irrelevant.

Comment: In the same sense, *goddessship* contains the grapheme *sh* once, and only two *s*. And in fact, a printing press type might have a ligatur *letter* for *sh* in the typesetting sense of letter, I guess (though I only know that of *ff* for a fact).

Comment: @ColinFine <ij> is "officially" two letters https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IJ_(digraph) (really, seems to depend on who you ask? (I don't speak Dutch)). For Welsh, the resemblance seems relevant for some frames of the original question, e.g., trying to identify and correct typos.

Answer (score 10):

Japanese has a prefix *ō-*, meaning "big" and pronounced as a long "o" (as if pronouncing two "o"s in a row), which in kana writing is おお.  If this prefix is added to any word starting with お, you'll get three おs in a row: おおおじ *oo-oji* "great-grandfather", おおおく *oo-oku* "great-interior" = "inner palace" (of the shogun's castle), etc.

In *kanji* writing there's 御御御付 *o-mi-o-tsuke* "miso soup", an unusual orthography exploiting the fact that 御 can be pronounced both *o-* and *mi-*.  I like to think that the creator of this orthography had a sense of humor; reading it feels like a puzzle (and it doesn't really respect the etymology of the word, "miso broth", for which 御味御付 or 御味御汁  would be better ways of writing it).

If you're more interested in sound than writing, there are several cases where a sequence of two long *ō*s follow each other, making for an extra-long sound; e.g. *hōō* "Pope", *sōō* "suitable", *Tōō* "Eastern Europe" etc.  Likewise with long "e" there’s *kēē* "management", *sēē* "elite".

Comment: [子子子子子子子子子子子子](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ono_no_Takamura#Takamura_in_later_literature), you may now argue that's not a word oe whether words are to be defined as distinct from phrases.

Comment: Don’t forget 東欧を覆おう ‘let’s cover Eastern Europe’, which is transcribed _Tōō (w)o ōō_, pronounced /toːoː o oːoː/.

Comment: Transcribing えい in Sino-Japanese compounds as ē is very unusual, although I have seen it in the odd book. Normally 経営 would be transcribed (e.g.) *keiei*.

Answer (score 9):

In Tagalog, maaari is a fairly common word used to mean "can" or "able to".

Answer (score 7):

In Romanian, I know of about 6-7 words that end in triple `'i'` - last `i` represents the definite article; some examples:

- *copiii* - the kids
- *viii* - the living ones
- *camionagiii* - the truck drivers

Answer (score 7):

In Arabic there is the verb تترك (ta-tar-ra-ka), which means "to be/become/act like the Turks". This verb, when conjugated in the second person singular form, becomes تتترك (ta-ta-tar-ra-ka) "you become Turkish".

Note that this letter "ت" is repeated only in writing, not phonetically. This is possible because in Arabic the majority of short vowels aren't written so usually a letter will represent a consonant-vowel combination. If you're looking for a "triple sound" you won't find any. For more about syllable structure in Arabic, [here's the Wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_phonology#Phonotactics)

Answer (score 6):

In Finnish, there are many words where the letter "k" drops out in certain case forms, and this occasionally creates a sequence of three identical vowels:

*vaaka* "scale (for weighing)" : genitive *vaa'an* "of (the) scale"

*raaka* "raw" : genitive *raa'an*

As you can see, the orthographic convention is to put an apostrophe ("heittomerkki") in the place where the lost consonant would have appeared. This is done wherever the loss of "k" results in a sequence of two or more identical vowels: *reikä* ("hole") : genitive *rei'in*, *liuku* ("slide") : gen. *liu'un*, and so on.

Answer (score 6):

In French, you can say créée or créées, as the feminine past-tense fo créer, which is to create in English. For the past tense of any verb consisting of être, (être né) or to be born, we add an extra e for the female conjugation. An example of this in a sentence is. Les filles d'esprit ont été créées il y a 5,000 années, (the spirit girls were created 5,000 years ago).

Surprisingly, you can also find some words in English with three consecutive letters in them, but, they are not vowels. The feminine grammar for godship is goddessship, which has three of the letter, s, in a row. So does headmistressship, but again, these are not vowels. Hope this helped! :)

Answer (score 6):

In Hebrew, two different sequences of four identical letters can occur:

- וווו. This is a word on its own. It means "and his hook".
- ממממ. This sequence occurs in words such as ממממן (from a financier), ממממנו (from his financier) and other similar forms. In addition, it occurs in words such as ממממש (from an implementer), ממממשו (from his implementer) and other similar forms.

Fun fact, in ממממנם (from their financier) and ממממשם (from their implementer), the final letter ם is actually just the letter מ in its 'final form'. So these 6 letter words contain the letter מ five times.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't uncommon in Tamil e.g:

- பற்றற்றான்
- அப்பப்பா
- திதததத்தத்

---

- https://www.quora.com/What-are-words-of-any-language-containing-three-of-the-same-letter-in-a-row
- https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-only-English-word-with-three-consecutive-repeated-letters
- https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-word-any-language-that-contains-4-same-letters-in-the-row
- https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/words-with-same-letter-three-times-in-a-row/

Comment: what do these words mean in English?

Answer (score 5):

In greek there is the word ''αντιιικός'' (antiviral) from ''αντι-'' and ''-ιικός'' (viral)

Comment: Please add more information. Answers are supposed to be long and with a lot of details.

Answer (score 4):

In "créées" we find three times the letter 'e' but French people say only [kʁee] (with two 'e'), the final 'e' being dropped.
"créées" : past participle of "créer" : feminine, plural ("Les étoiles ont été créées il y a longtemps." -> The stars have been created a long time ago.)

Comment: Interesting point, but the question is about the letters and not the sounds.

Comment: Apparently, in some accents of French the "e" at the end of "créée" is realized as length on the preceding vowel: it is pronounced /kʁeeː/.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of answers deal with regular orthography, but triple letters are often and colloquially used in non-standard spellings to express emotion or emphasis, e.g. German *Ich hab sich sooo lieb* "I love you sooo" or English *boooring*. I am sure other languages have examples of this, too.

Comment: Ich hab dich....