# Any world languages having multiple-letter-based or single-ideogram-based syllables where three or more consecutive syllables of any word repeat?

Tags: morphology, orthography, list-of-languages, language-games

My question is related to [this interesting question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/9713/examples-of-words-containing-the-same-letter-three-times-in-a-row-in-any-languag), but instead of looking for letters within words which happen to appear repeated three or more times in a row, I'm looking for consecutive identical sequences of letters (which could even be single ideograms in idogram-based languages such as Chinese) within words which happen to repeat three or more times consecutively within the same word.

Hypotetical examples of sought words (the parts in round brackets are optional and of arbitrary length if present):

- A word having the hypothetical form "(qrstuv)**abcabcabc**(wxyz)".
- A word having the hypothetical form "(阿比西)**拉拉拉**(马巴计)" [read: (ābǐxī)lālālā(mǎbājì)]. As most Chinese words are two, three, or at most four characters long, and repeated idiograms tend to come in pairs, I don't think this is possible in Chinese, but you never know, perhaps some esoteric example or an example given in some other archaic ideogrammatic language may fit the pattern! :-)

Thanks!

Comment: How about Japanese 御御御付け *omiotsuke*? Does that meet your criteria?

Comment: Interesting. But I was looking for three repeated consecutive syllables with the same pronunciation. Anyways, your example is intriguing because the first three ideograms are all pronounced differently within the same word. My guess is that such combination must be quite uncommon. :-O

Comment: Is there also an example like the one you gave where the three consecutive idiograms/syllables are also _pronounced_ the same (which is what my original question was asking for)?

Comment: Ah, I see, your edit changes the question so that it asks about pronunciation rather than just orthography.  I'm afraid I can't think of any examples at the moment…

Answer (score 7):

In the order they occurred to me:

Serbo-Croat: **mamama/мамама** — dative, instrumental & locative plural of *mama* "mom".

Bulgarian: **кантатата** "the cantata", and any other feminine nouns ending in -тата with the suffixed definite article.

Russian: **нененецкий** "non-[Nenets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nenets_people)"

Comment: Very interesting! :-)

Answer (score 5):

There are several languages with grammaticalized [reduplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication) with three grades, triplication, which is exactly the thing you are asking about. You can read about these cases on the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication), [here](http://www.ccunix.ccu.edu.tw/~lngproc/Tsay-Myers-TTR-handout.pdf) or [here](http://idiom.ucsd.edu/~rose/Tigre.pdf).

One example from [aforementioned handout](http://www.ccunix.ccu.edu.tw/~lngproc/Tsay-Myers-TTR-handout.pdf) is from Southern Min:

- 1 repetition: 紅 ang “red”
- 2 repetitions: 紅紅 ang-ang “somewhat red”
- 3 repetitions: 紅紅紅 ang-ang-ang “very red”

These cases are very rare though.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the term `reduplication`. Your answer is perhaps the most interesting so far. Are there any other such examples in Chinese (with three or more such words)? Also, isn't `紅` supposed to be pronounced `hóng`? Where did you get the pronounciation from, I'm curious. I was familiar with similar examples (such as 白白的云朵: báibái de yúnduǒ, and plenty of others）involving two repetitions, but had never seen three. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, OK, now I see the document in your link, Southern Min as spoken by the MinZu minority ethnic group in China. Very, very interesting! Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Dutch [Hottentot**tentententen**toonstelling](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hottentottententententoonstelling) Hottentots' tents' exhibition, in use for many years.  Other "lettergreepstapels" (syllable pile-ups) include **kerkerkerkerker** the erker (bay window) of the kerk (chapel) in the kerker (jail), even if bay windows are rare in such buildings; more plausible although not proven by online photographs is Lek**kerkerkerkerkerker**, a bay window of a church in a [town](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lekkerkerk) on the river Lek.  See https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opperlans.

Answer (score 3):

Since numeral symbols are ideograms, even English has such sequences, for example '666' is often [pronounced](http://youtu.be/jsmcDLDw9iw?t=1m50s) as 'six-six-six'.

Answer (score 2):

Hahaha

(English).

I would think that other onomatopoeia also could fit your requirements.

Comment: What other onomatopoeia? Please augment your answer with more examples. I'm interested.

Comment: @John Sonderson Not entirely a onomatopoeia, but what about: yayaya http://nb.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=yayaya

Comment: Interesting. Although I always thought the spelling would have been: `yah, yah, yah`, which is three words and not a single word. Regards.

Comment: @John Sonderson Santa Claus saying hohoho (still English) is another example

Answer (score 1):

There is the following fun sentence in German with a fivefold repetition of the syllable "ni" (spelled "ni" or "nie", but with identical pronunciation):

- *Leider sah Paganini nie Ninive* (Unfortunately, Paganini never saw Niniveh.)

Comment: Buffalo, etc...

Answer (score 1):

In Spanish you can say **la yaya ya yace**, which means "The granny is lying already".